# Has anyone shipped equipment to use in Canada without expensive custom broker fees?

Tags: equipment

We ship an AURAL up to collaborators in Canada so they can put it on one of their oceanographic moorings.  A year later they recover and send it back to us.  I don't understand why we have to pay a customs broker to ship it up. We aren't importing it into the country, it is actually just passing through their country on the way to the mooring site that is outside the Canadian EEZ.  Has anyone hit on the right combination of paperwork to get gear through the Canadian border and onto a ship?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if in the end it helps to avoid broker fees, but

- get and learn about a ATA Carnet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Carnet for your instruments
- minimize custom interaction:

  - check with ship handler if you can send it directly to the port of departure

If all sounds difficult and you cannot bring the instruments yourself and convince custom agent, I guess that is why custom broker exist

Comment: An ATA may be accepted but I suspect that a one year use would not qualify for a temporary stay.

Comment: @sm1, Note OP indicates that instruments are NOT used in Canada but only on transit and used in international waters (outside Canadian EEZ). So, they transit Canada twice, but... as you note in your answer that is why there exist brokers to know all the regulations.

Comment: yes, saw that. I wonder how customs considers EEZ. It looks like a broker with this kind of rare expertise would be needed. I worked in IT at a large customs broker in Canada for 11 years and such a case seems rare. A relevant broker could help here and save unnecessary expenses and delays.

Comment: AURAL: Autonomous Underwater Recorder for Acoustic Listening

Answer (score 0):

An individual (or other entity) owning some goods going inbound through a Canadian border is responsible for getting it cleared with the government customs agency, and the broker does the support for this task, they do not do the actual clearance, which is always the responsibility of the goods owner. The support includes electronic communication with the customs computer and some assistance for the assignment of the valid code(s). The Canadian government provides information and support for individuals to clear goods without the use of a broker. The learning slope and process delays could be detrimental to the self-service option. Maybe you could find a broker who for a fee could show you how to do it by yourself. You may still need to pay duty and taxes, depending on the applicable laws, with a possible refund a year later, on the way out. A broker could also help with the refund process, e.g. filling the right forms. There's quite a bit of legal and process expertise involved and this is why it's hard to do on your own. It's a bit like going to court and being your own lawyer. One could do it but it is difficult and risky.

Comment: Btw, brokers fees vary and one can shop around for a lower fee.